# Aligning text inside an <option> tag

Tags: php, html, alignment

I have a `select` tag with a lot of options. Every option has a `name` and a `date` which both should be printed in every `<option>`.

I want to align the list like this:

```
Name    Date
Name    Date
Name    Date
```

Since every name has different length, I wrote this code:

```
//Start of the option text//

//Always print 20 characters, even if the name is longer//
print  ">".substr($eventsArr[$j]->GetName(),0 ,20); 

//If the name is shorter then 20 chars//                        
if(strlen($eventsArr[$j]->GetName()) < 20) 
{
    //Add missing chars (20 - the length of the string) with spaces//
    for($t = 0; $t < 20 - (strlen($eventsArr[$j]->GetName())); $t++)
    {
       print "&nbsp";
    }
}
print "" .$newDate."</option>\n"; //Then print the date//
```

I'm getting the correct amount of spaces completed. But as you can see, the alignment is not 100%:

[image: Alignment Result]

I'm guessing its because every letter has a different width in pixels. So... Is there any way of doing this kind of alignment ? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use a Monospaced font for this. It's what they were designed for.

Comment: I've added this: `print "<option style=\"font-family: monospace;\"; value=".$eventsArr[$j]->GetEventGUID();` to each option, but I don't see any change. Where should I append the style ?

Comment: Ahh ok, I've added the `monospace` style to the `<select>` tag and it is working perfectly, Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Option elements were not meant to be formatted that way. Using a monospace font would be the way to achieve alignment, but that would make the text look ugly, and monospace fonts are less readable, too. Moreover, not all browsers honor font family settings for `option` elements; for example, IE 9 does not.

The workaround, or alternative approach, is to use a set of radio buttons instead of a `select` element. Then you can use a table:

```
 <table>
 <tr><td><input type=radio id=a1> <label for=a1>Name</label>
     <td>Date
 ...
 </table>
```

This handles the alignment, and this also lets you specify the font used for the labels in a manner that works across browsers.

If there is a large number of alternatives, you might consider setting a height and vertical scrolling for the table. But it might be better to let users just scroll down the page as needed, instead of having two levels of scrolling.

Comment: Thanks, you mean each row consist of 2 columns, one for the name and one for the date ?

Comment: It is working fine with IE9. I've inserted the `monospace` inside the `select` tag.

Comment: @Alon_A, yes I meant a two-column table. Or more columns if needed. I still think it’s the best approach.

Regarding the use of fonts in select menus, you’re right: IE 9 lets you set the font if you set it on `select`. I tested the more natural way, setting it on `option` (more logical, since the text is primarily `option` element content).